# Unable to send Firebase "data" messages from Advance REST Client to Android apps

Tags: android, rest, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase in my Android application developed using Android Studio. I'm able to send Firebase Notification messages from the Firebase console and successfully receive the same in the app.

Now, I need to send data payload messages to my Android app. Since it's not possible to send using Firebase console, I'm trying to achieve the same using Advance REST Client.

[image: Screenshot of Advanced Rest Client]

But I'm getting the following error in Advance REST Client when I tried to send:

```
The requested URL can't be reached

The service might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Search Google for chrome network error 137

net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED
```

Here's my request :

Request URL: `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

Raw Headers:

```
Authorization: key="server-key"
Content-Type: application/json
```

Raw payload :

```
{
    "registration_ids" : "[{"fcm-token"}]",
    "data": {
        "key1" : "value1",
        "key2" : "value2",
        "other_key" : true
    }
}
```

What's wrong in my request? Please help.

**Note** : "fcm-token" and "server-key" are replaced with real values in the actual request.

Comment: make sure if any AUTH is enable in database of firebase

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ, May I know how do I check that?

Comment: Database ==> Rules

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ In Rules : {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}

Comment: The error you're receiving doesn't seem to come from FCM at all. Can you try using a different machine (hopefully, using a different network) and see if this issue still persists? I've seen this [Chrome thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/tpBfLA3BQg4). It might help. For a simpler testing, you can also try and just send a simple cURL request. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/8242/firebase-cloud-messaging/26480/sending-downstream-messages-via-curl#t=20170104060910550112).

Comment: @AL. I've tried changing the network. Still the same error. I'll try in another machine. I'll have to setup cURL in my machine to use it.

Comment: Sure. Good luck. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: { "rules": { ".read": "truel", ".write": "true" } }

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ , Should I change the rules like above?